# Can I install a Windows 8.1 desktop software (exe file) on Pipo W4 (Windows 8.1) tablet?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, tablet

Is it possible to install Windows 8.1 desktop software on [Pipo W4](http://www.pipo-store.com/pipo-w4-windows-8-1-tablet-pc-quad-core-8-inch-1280x800-ips-hdmi-otg-bluetooth-wifi-1gb-16gb.html)?
[image: Pipo W4]

```
Model  PIPO W4 
Screen Information   8 inch multi point IPS Capacitive Screen 
Resolution  1280x800px 
CPU  Intel Z3735G Quad core; max 1.83GHz
Operation System  windows 8.1
RAM  1GB
ROM 16GB
Extend Card  Support TF card memory extended
Camera  Front Camera:0.3MP 
Rear Camera:2.0MP 
Bluetooth  YES 
GPS  N/A 
HDMI  YES 
OTG  YES 
WIFi  Yes, 802.11 b/g/n 
Video  MPEG4,H264,H263,VC1,etc. 
Music  MP3,MIDI,WAV,AAC,PCM,AMR,WMA,etc. 
Ebook  UMD,TXT,PDF,HTML,RTF,FB2 
Other Applications  File Manager,OfficeSuite,Google Search,Browser,Gallery,Clock,Calculator, Calendar,iReader,Email,etc 
Language  Support Multi-language
Connectivity  
   1 x Micro USB port  
   1 x HDMI 
   1 x TF Card slot 
   1 x Earphone port 
Battery  4500mAh
Power Device    Adapter Input 100/240V Output 5V-2A 
Net Weight  364g
```

Comment: It doesn't say it's running Windows RT 8.1, so my guess would be yes.

Comment: Is the question now answered or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the tablet has a x86 CPU (Intel Z3735G) with a normal Windows 8.1, not Windows RT. Here you can install normal 32Bit desktop software like Firefox.